# How do I exclude a specific file from my msbuild AfterBuild target

Tags: configuration, msbuild

I have this msbuild target in my csproj file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <CreateItem Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.dll'" Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="IlmergeAssemblies" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\tools\IlMerge\Ilmerge.exe&quot; /targetplatform:&quot;v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319&quot; /ndebug /out:@(MainAssembly) &quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(IlmergeAssemblies->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" />
    <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

This works like a charm. But I want it to exclude a specific file and tried to tweak it:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <CreateItem Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.dll' AND '%(Filename)' != 'Foo.dll'" Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="IlmergeAssemblies" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\tools\IlMerge\Ilmerge.exe&quot; /targetplatform:&quot;v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319&quot; /ndebug /out:@(MainAssembly) &quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(IlmergeAssemblies->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" />
    <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

However, this doesn't work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think (by memory) that %(Filename) will be 'Foo'

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just figured out the same. Would you like to drop an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It happened to me once but I was not sure and couldn't test it now..that is the reason I put it as a comment. I have created an answer now. Happy you fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

%(Filename) contains only the name of the file.

So you can test **%(Filename)' != 'Foo'**:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
<CreateItem Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.dll' AND '%(Filename)' != 'Foo'" Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="IlmergeAssemblies" />
</CreateItem>
<Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\tools\IlMerge\Ilmerge.exe&quot; /targetplatform:&quot;v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319&quot; /ndebug /out:@(MainAssembly) &quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(IlmergeAssemblies->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" />
<Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```