# how to tell VS to copy native dll to "final destination folder"

Tags: build, visual-studio-2012

In my project I have

- native c++ dll project (output to x64/)
- c++/cli wrapper (output to x64/)
- several c# projects (output to projectName\bin\x64)

While building first dll is copied to "x64/"
Then wrapper is copied to "x64/". At final stage wrappper dll is copied to "projectName\bin\x64" folder, but original native dll didn't copied.

I need native dll also go to the final folder, so I can run application, how to do that?

I have tried to add "native dll" as a dependency, but VS says that it is not possible.

**upd** Also if I copy dll myself and then debug I can't go into native dll, I receive "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" error. So I assume this problems are connected. I want native dll to be copied and I want to be able to debug.

**upd** This answer helped me to debug [Cannot Debug Unmanaged Dll from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744888/cannot-debug-unmanaged-dll-from-c-sharp) however I still have to copy dll myself. What is odd because every time I build project I have a warning that "native dll" project is out of date.

Comment: you could use xcopy as a post-build step?

Comment: @penguat i have nativde dll project. i have cli wrapper. i expect some straightforward way to have everything in one place. this is VERY common question. do everyone in this situation use `xcopy`?

Comment: I think everyone uses post-build steps. Not being everyone, that's not authoritative, but it's probably the best documented way of achieving what you want. The bounty should hopefully attract more authoritative answers soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you'll need to use a post-build step. Here are a couple of examples:

[How do I exclude a specific file from my msbuild AfterBuild target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120819/how-do-i-exclude-a-specific-file-from-my-msbuild-afterbuild-target)

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BinFiles Include="bin\$(ConfigurationName)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(BinFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(BinFiles->'$(ProjectDir)\relativePathToDirectory" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: do everyone who use native dll and cli wrapper do something like that in their solutions?

Comment: I doubt it. You might be able to include it in the project as an output item, for example, and anyone who isn't using MSBuild (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582380/305256) is very unlikely to do it this way (since this is a feature of MSBuild)